# Help regarding Triggers

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a table (TableA). On this table I am creating a trigger which will insert a row into another table(TableB) for insert, update and delete actions made on TableA. My intention is to track modification on TableA.

I am having single trigger to do this. 
(create trigger trig_name  before insert or update or delete on TableA... – Kind of).

Now I need what is the actual operation performed on the table A.When the trigger insert a row into TableB, I want actual operation performed on the TableA also to be inserted in a column.

Is there any possibilities to capture what operation performed on TableA with single trigger or Do I have to create separate trigger for each of the DML statement operations?

TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm):

> Detecting the DML Operation that Fired a Trigger
>
> If more than one type of DML operation can fire a trigger (for example, ON INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE OF emp), the trigger body can use the conditional predicates INSERTING, DELETING, and UPDATING to check which type of statement fire the trigger.
>
> Within the code of the trigger body, you can execute blocks of code depending on the kind of DML operation that fired the trigger:

```
IF INSERTING THEN ... END IF;
IF UPDATING THEN ... END IF;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following predicates in the PL/SQL:

```
IF INSERTING THEN ... END IF;
IF UPDATING THEN ... END IF;
IF DELETING THEN ... END IF;
```